# + operation in Java indicates which OOP concept?

Tags: java, oop

If we have `c=a+b`, `a=5`, and `b=6`, then `c=11`. Now if `a="Jack"`, `b="Reacher"`, and `c=a+b`, then `c="JackReacher"`. Which OOP concept is shown by the `+` operator here? Is it polymorphism?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading

Comment: You should read what SOF really is and what questions you are asking here.

Comment: without defining datatype, how u can say this?

Comment: If it's Java, then `+` operator does not exhibit any OOP concepts. In most languages on JVM stack operators are either is their own thing, or methods with non-latin names. There is no polymorphism, because there is nothing like a class or interface that would define `+` operation for all possible implementors of it (I'm not even sure such interface is possible).

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks It’s SO; there’s no F in there ;)

Comment: @bfontaine there is in my head! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator is an example of operator overloading which is a form of *ad hoc* polymorphism.

According to the classic Computer Science literature, there are many forms of polymorphism:

- Java generics are an example of *parametric polymorphism*.
- Java's support for subclassing and interfaces constitute an example of *subtype polymorphism*.
- Operator overloading and method overloading are examples of *ad hoc polymorphism*.

(Parametric polymorphism and subtype polymorphism are subcases of *universal polyporphism*; i.e. they apply / can be applied to most types, and are intrinsic to the type system.  By contrast, *ad hoc polymorphism* is piecemeal, and in most cases are not intrinsic to the type system.  For example, the Java type system would not be fundamentally different if all methods in a class or interface had to have different name, or all (currently overloaded) operators had different symbols.)

Subtype polymorphism (in one form or another) is a key component of OO programming languages.  The other types of polymorphism are not key to OO, though many / most OO languages support them.

So ... you could argue that `+` does is not an example of *any* OO concept.

---

It is also worth noting that there is subtype polymorphism under the hood of the `+` string concatenation operator:

```
SomeClass s = ...

System.out.println("s is " + s);
```

The `+` operator in this case calls `toString()` on the `s` object to render it as a `String`.  That call involves subtype polymorphism.

(Someone commented that `+` is polymorphic because it relies on `StringBuilder` calls under the hood.  However, that is an *implementation choice* not a fundamental property of the Java language.  Read the JLS if you don't believe me!)

---

For more information on the different kinds of polymorphism, read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) on the subject.  The "classic" paper on this topic ["On understanding types, data abstraction and polymorphism"](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/OnUnderstanding.A4.pdf) by Luca Cardelli and David Wegner.

Comment: I did not actually mean that + is polymorphic because it involves virtual calls. What I was saying is it can be viewed as message passing because of those calls. But I myself is of an opinion that operators in Java do not exhibit any concept of OO, which you yourself said.

Comment: I always understood "ad hoc" to mean "separately defined for every shape" (if we interpret "polymorphism" as "dealing with many shapes"), whereas "parametric" means "treating the shape as an unknown". Haskell's implementation of ad hoc polymorphism are type classes, which are deeply integrated into the type system, but that doesn't make them less ad hoc.

Comment: Well, that is not what if means according to the literature.  Please read the sources I linked to.

Comment: I am using the definition by Strachey, the definition you linked to is the one by Cardelli and Wegner, which is basically a refinement and generalization of Strachey's definition. Neither in Cardelli and Wegner's nor in Strachey's definition can I find anything that says that "ad-hoc polymorphism" means "polymorphism that is not a fundamental part of the type system". Nor can I find something that contradicts my interpretation.

Comment: I accept that C&W doesn't say that explicitly.  However, it is still patently true for the exemplar varieties of ad-hoc polymorphism in C&W.  Operator and method overloading are not fundamental because the programmer (or PL designer) could just invent a different name for the overloaded method / operator.  Coercion (as described by C&W) is not fundamental because you can just insist that the programmer writes the "semantically necessary type conversions" explicitly.

Comment: What C&W actually says is this: *"Ad-hoc  polymorphism
  is  obtained  when  a  function  works,  or
appears to work, on several different types (which may not exhibit a common structure) and may behave in
unrelated ways for each type."*  There is no mention of "shapes" or whether things are defined separately or not.  Indeed, many kinds of ad-hoc polymorphism are intrinsic to the language ... not "defined" in use code.  The way I think of it is that C&W actually uses *ad-hoc* to mean NOT *universal*.  It is not a clearly defined category at all.

Answer (score 2):

Primitives aren't objects in Java, and operators aren't message sends, ergo, there is no object-orientation going on in your code. Primitives and classes define Abstract Data Types, not objects, only interfaces define objects; there are no interfaces in your code, so there are no objects and the code isn't object-oriented, thus the very question which object-oriented concepts are used in a piece of code which doesn't use object-orientation is non-sensical.

Note that polymorphism is not an object-oriented concept.

Comment: `+` operator is overloaded for `String -> String -> String`, to be fair, and it could be seen as message passing, but there's nothing like polymorphism, since all _classes_ that are accepted by operators are final.

Comment: `String` is a class. Classes define Abstract Data Types in Java, not objects. There is no message passing (which Java calls "virtual method dispatch" or something like that) there. If `String` were an interface and `+` were a method, then it would indeed be OO.

Comment: In Java, runtime `+` for `String`s is implemented with `StringBuilder::append`, which is  a virtual call.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov - That is an implementation detail.  The JLS allows but does not require a `StringBuilder` to be used.  OTOH ... `Object::toString` calls are mandated.